# Drive letter missing from Navigation Pane in File Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

So my issue is that my D: drive does not appear in the list of drives in the *Navigation Pane* even though it is just a regular partition like the C: and E: partitions. Even H: and Z: appear and they are an external USB hard drive and CD drive.
As you can see in the attached image. The D: drive can be seen in the main window when standing on *This PC* so it is there.

Any ideas how to make it show up in the Navigation Pane on the left?
[image: File Explorer]

Comment: I'm not even sure how you got the drive letters to show up like that in that left pane it eh first place...??  If you expand "This PC" in that left-hand pane, does it show all the drives?

Comment: Like @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 it is funny they are all there in the first place. By default, only external drives should appear there.

Comment: Is C: an internal drive?

Comment: Interesting. So I was like "why isn't D: there?" and you guys are saying "Why are C: and E: there?"
(C: is the system drive and on an internal hard disk)

Comment: On the topic of "how'd you get C: to show up?", I have a Windows 10 Enterprise VM that shows the C: drive. Not sure if the "Enterprise" part or the "VM" part is what made the C: drive show up, but might shine some light?